# Best beginner method for producing MJ in big dig pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

What is the best way to produce energy in the big dig pack considering I have only just started. I have built a Tinker Table and a power gauntlet and I'm looking to produce enough energy to power the glove and what not. I am looking at solar generators, but is this the best method? Also, if you'd like, may you please suggest what I should really be aiming for in terms of energy production. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Unless Big Dig has something more exotic, your entry-level MJ engine is a Sterling Engine. Feed it coal, get MJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method i usually use for beginning big-dig is to do a quick mining stint and get some iron and redstone.

From here I build a few Stirling engines and hook these up to a few of the pipes that allow a current to be carried and then this can be hooked up to any other devices you want fairly easily, by just extending the piping.

Be wary of too much piping though, it will eventually split the current up to too many systems and provide each with very small amounts of power, ideally this is only used as a basic start-up method for a small (2-3) amount of machines.

Stirling Engines are powered by coal, or any other item that burns, which makes them an ideal starting engine, but I advise against leaving them running for too long unattended, they have a tendency to get, explodey.

I don't suggest starting with a redstone engine, they just don't seem to provide enough power to maintain a steady flow.

If you are handy with redstone and some timers though you can set up an auto clock that powers the engines down automatically after a set time, then turns them on again at a set time allowing them to cool off a bit.

Comment: For a simple failsafe, use a wooden pressure plate as your redstone source and drop a useless item on it.  It will despawn in 5 minutes and turn off the engine.

Answer (score 2):

Stirling engines require a constant source of coal whilst solar generators need a large resource investment as well as energy cubes. But if you have enough for a tinker table & a glove, this should not be too great a problem.

However, another solution that has been overlooked is the use of heat generators. These require few resources to start up & produce a constant source of energy. I reccomend placing the lava on top of the heat generator (with empty space around the generator) to maximise the power produced.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, there are a lot of solutions to this particular one. I'd advise skipping stirling engines altogether, as the amount of energy that they produce is pretty lacking. They're OK for the beginning stages, but past that they're just a nuisance.

For someone who's already got a steel casing, I'd recommend a couple of wind turbines. If you're building in the plains biome, you might have to nerd pole up a bit with wire to get to a good spot for the turbines, but they're definitely worth it. If you generally build on top of the nether (like I do), wind turbines are just about the best source of power up there, as wind turbines generate power based on elevation, meaning power up the wazoo. It's easily the best power source if wired correctly, being able to parallel-power something like eight machines at once.

Answer (score 1):

My plan with the server I'm currently playing on, was to do quite a lot of mining using the tinkers construct tools, then use those resources to make magmatic engines, then set up a pump in the nether using phased piping to pump it into a tank in my house, the lava then went from this tank to the magmatic engine which was then attached to my machines (first of all directly then via redstone energy conduits). This method produces MJ. If you want EU just replace the magmatic engines with geothermal generators although this is not possible in the bigdig pack now.

Answer (score 0):

I generally start with wind turbines because their pretty cheap and produce an efficient amount of eletricity to power a few machines

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is actually EU, not MJ.  Which might cause some confusion with people trying to answer your question.

That said, the Solar Generator and subsequent Advanced Solar Generators are probably where you want to start since Big Dig doesn't have a standard coal powered generator.  You can get other generators that supplement your power such as biofuel, hydro and heat but they are fairly weak and in some cases will require you already have power and other machines to create the fuel for them.  Since Big Dig is all about gathering resources, creating an Advanced Solar Panel shouldn't be an issue.

Hook whatever you have up to an Energy Cube to store your energy (this is especially important for solar panels since you want to store up energy during the day to save up for use over-night).

As for end-game power, Big Dig is sort of strange and a lot of the time MJ is actually more important than EU because of the mod line-up.  There are unlimited energy setups, you should watch Youtube tutorials on those.

Answer (score -3):

I agree with EU thing but don't agree with it completely. First I am pretty new and i have to use the recipe mode lot but as far as i know Big dig is digging so just keep mining for iron red stone and stuff and then place about 4-8 pumps in the nether at least 4 blocks far away from each other then place 4 or 3 red stone engines around it and activate it. wait and the red stone engines will go to it's maximal performance which is when it turns red. Don't worry these won't explode, then place the ender tanks on top of the pumps. then it should start filling up the tank in few seconds. now go back to the over world place the same amount of ender tanks and color code them on top which is the 3 white stripes. then do the same to the nether ones (only two of them should be color coded same! 1 in nether and 1 in over world). Now u can build lots of magma tic engine all facing towards and machine or energy storage or a cable. Now get a CRESCENT hammer and right/left click (forgot) to the machines to turn it into output so it output energy! this is important and do the same to the ender tank make blue side of the ring facing up wards into orange facing upwards. This means the pump will pull lava infinitely and transport it to the tank just above it. Then the tank with the same color code will receive the lava across dimensions and will out put it into the water proof pipe which leads to individual magma tic engines.

What you will need for the least one is...
energy cell
magma tic engine (around 4 of them per tank)
2 ender tank
2 color dies (or you can leave it blank if you are not going to place any more)
water proof pipe
and last but not least........
CRESCENT HAMMER!